# How to Update Image on Button Click Command

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism-4

View has a button and Image control.I have bound the button command to a delegateCommand on the ViewModel, which opens a file dialog for the user to choose an Image.The Context "object" for View contains a property "Icon" which is of type byte[].I have bound the Icon to the Image control.The question is how do i display the selected image file on the image control?.

Xaml:

```
<Button  x:Name="dlgIconbtn" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" Content="Choose Icon" MaxWidth="120" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Grid.Column="3" Source="{Binding AppItem.Icon,Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"
               Width="25" Height="25"/>
```

Comment: tags don't add anything to your title.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Your Converter is working fine.
Now when `OpenFileCommand` fires user selects image and you update `App.Icon` property with new `Byte[]`.
Now please RaiseProperty changed event on Icon so Binding get refreshed.

I do not think you need any Code here.

if still not working then please update you Question with full code XAML + ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a property "ImgSource" in the viewModel which is bound to the source of the ImageControl.Whenever a user selects an image using the button command i set the image file contents to the "ImgSource" and it works.